# How can I avoid this if statement

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, generics, if-statement

I have an enum

```
public enum Vehicle {
    CAR("CAR", "Car"), PUSHBIKE("PUSHBIKE", "PuschBike");

    public  boolean isCar()
{
    ...
}

    public  boolean isPushBike()
{
    ....
}
}
```

I have a 2 DAO `CarDAO` and `PushBikeDAO` which is are implementing a BaseDao

I have a JSF managed bean somthing like this

```
public class JsfManagedBean {

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    private BaseDAO baseDao;

    public void Search()
    {
           //I need to get rid of this if statement
        if (vehicle.isCar())
        {
            baseDao = new CarDao;
            baseDao.search();
        }
        else if(vehicle.isPushBike())
        {
            baseDao = new PushBike;
            baseDao.search();
        }
      //Please Note each type of search is very different call to an other party's Jar
    }
}
```

I am trying to get rid of this if statement possibly by using generics or any proper OO technique
may be something like

```
baseDao = new baseDaoImpl<getClass(vehicle.getcode())>
```

where if `vehicle.getcode()` returns String value Car I do have a model class Car.

Just loud thinking (clinching the straws really :)).

This is an offshot of this question of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332873/how-can-i-improve-this-design-that-calls-third-party-methods-from-jsf-based-front)

Comment: Cross the street when you see it coming :-)

Comment: Couldn't this be done with dependency injection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let each of the enum constants define their respective DAO classes:

```
public enum Vehicle {
  CAR("CAR", "Car"){
    public BaseDAO getNewDAO(){
      return new CarDAO();
    }
  },
  PUSHBIKE("PUSHBIKE", "PuschBike"){
    public BaseDAO getNewDAO() {
      return new PushBikeDAO();
    }
  };

  Vehicle(String a, String b){/* ... */}
  //this forces every enum constant to implement a getNewDAO() method:
  abstract BaseDAO getNewDAO();
}
```

This way, you can use:

```
public void Search() {
  baseDao = vehicle.getNewDAO();
  baseDao.search();
}
```

Take a look at the [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) if you'd like to know more. Enums are my preferred way to use the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Add a method to the enum that calls new and returns the right dao.

Comment: Would not I just in that case be shifting the if statement from one class to other? any possibility of a code snippet please

Comment: This would be a mixture of a factory and strategy pattern imho. And it's they way to go here.

Comment: I am humbled with all the great replies and upvoting all really good approaches but since can only accept one :) I will give it to @f1sh

Comment: f1sh needs the rep more than I do.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a factory method, like so:

```
public class JsfManagedBean {

    private static final Map<Vehicle,BaseDAO> daos;
    static {
        Map<Vehicle,BaseDAO> tmp = new HashMap<Vehicle,BaseDAO>();
        tmp.put(Vehicle.CAR,new CarDAO());
        tmp.put(Vehicle.BIKE,new BikeDAO());
        daos = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp);
    }
    public static getDao(Vehicle v) {
        return daos.get(v);
    }

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    private BaseDAO baseDao;

    public void Search()
    {
            baseDao = getDao(vehicle);
            baseDao.search();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not create a new instance of the DAO object on each call to ``Search()``.

Comment: @f1sh no, it doesn't. It illustrates the basic concept which can be ran with if they need a new DAO object. Personally, I wouldn't want a DAO that required me to create a new instance each time, but that's just me. I have one database, I don't need a new object. The DAO shouldn't have any state variables that can be mucked by multithreaded calls.

Comment: It was indeed a nice approach as well and I will keep in mind.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have more uses for DAO objects, you could make this code shorter:

```
if (vehicle.isCar()) new CarDao().search();
else if(vehicle.isPushBike()) new PushbikeDao().search();
```

With two alternatives, I'd stay with the `if` statement. If you had really many variants of vehicles, you could use a hash table keyed by the enum values and storing the DAO classes:

```
Map<Vehicle, Class> DAOClass = new HashMap<...>();
...
DAOClass.get(vehicle).getConstructor().newInstance().search();
```

Reflection is not *that* slow not to use here.